# D3 line goes off chart to left when I append multiple line graph divs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a page that allows user generation of multiple d3 charts based on the user pushing buttons to select a dataset. The first chart generates fine. The second chart generates but the lines starts off the chart to the lefthand side. Every additional chart has this same problem. Has anyone had similar issue? I'm not posting a specific line of code, because I'm not sure where the problem is? I'm hoping others have run into a similar issue.

This is an example of the code running. Click on the department buttons to start bringing up additional charts to see the problem. http://www.justingosses.com/cookCounty/Index.html

The code itself can be found on github. https://github.com/JustinGOSSES/JustinGOSSES.github.io

Any help would be appreciated. I haven't been able to find previous similar problems.

Comment: generally, you should include the code on your post as much as possible.  this makes the question able to be long-lived.  see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> The first chart generates fine. The second chart generates but the lines starts off the chart to the lefthand side. Every additional chart has this same problem.

Hard to tell without more detail here but I would say to look into the code that's generating the additional charts. Are you forgetting to reinitialize something? Is there a global variable (set when initializing the first chart) that could be messing things up? Are you setting the `x` domain and range correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks adilapapaya. Your suggestion that I wasn't reinitializing was exactly right. When a button was clicked to create a new chart, the new array of data was being added to the old array not replacing it. I had forgotten a var FinalArray = [] line to reset the array to empty that needed to go inside the function that supplies the data to the function that makes each new D3 chart.

I was missing this line : `var ArrayFinal = []`

Apparently if you create multiple line charts using the same function, and simply add data to the end of the data array each time, D3 was clever enough to only use the new data for the axis but not clever enough to only use new data for the lines?

Below is the function in question. I added line 2. The purpose of this function is to process a json dataset elsewhere and return a formatted array that is a subset of the original json. A department name and the data array are sent to the function that creates the D3 chart.

```
function findFunds(row, department) {
  var ArrayFinal = []     //<-- this is the line I missed
  var dates = ["1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"];      
  var date = [];
  //concats key and value names in data_json into array values good for display in D3.js
  for (each in dates) {
    date.push(dates[each].concat("0101"));
  };
  console.log(date)
  var appropriations = [];
  for (each in dates) {
    appropriations.push("Appropriations ".concat(dates[each]))
  };
  console.log(appropriations)
  var expenditures = [];
  for (each in dates) {
    expenditures.push("Expenditures ".concat(dates[each]))
  };
  console.log(expenditures)
  //creates an object with three keys/value pares, repeats over a loop
  for (each in dates) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.date = date[each];
    obj.appropriations = data_json[row][appropriations[each]];
    obj.expenditures = data_json[row][expenditures[each]];
    //throws the object created into an array
    ArrayFinal.push(obj);
  };  
  console.log(ArrayFinal);
  d3_mini(department, ArrayFinal);
};
```

and for reference, this was the function that creates my D3 line charts.

```
//D3 for second smaller funds vs. time by department starts here!
function d3_mini(department, ArrayFinal) {
  //////var data = ArrayFinal;
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 80},
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

  var area = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("step-after")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

  var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("step-after")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

  var svg = d3.select("#miniTimeChart").append("div").append("svg")
      .data(ArrayFinal)
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  function make_x_axis() {        
      return d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
           .orient("bottom")
           .ticks(20)
  }

  function make_y_axis() {        
      return d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(10)
  }

  // input prepared JSON of only data necessary for chart in appropriate format
  //d3.json(ArrayFinal, function(error, data) 
  var data = ArrayFinal;

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(String(d.date));
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          var money_temp = +d[name]/1000000
          return {date: d.date, temperature: money_temp};
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
    ]);

    svg.append("g")         
          .attr("class", "grid")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(make_x_axis()
              .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
              .tickFormat("")
          )

    svg.append("g")         
          .attr("class", "grid")
          .call(make_y_axis()
              .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
              .tickFormat("")
          )   

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Millions of Dollars");


    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
        .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
          .attr("class", "area")    
          .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

    city.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    city.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("font-size","12px"); 

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))             
        .attr("y", 6 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
        .text(department);
  };
```